# How to set default search by name of Many2One field from action window or tree view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have a customized tree view that can be accessed from my customized action window.

I would like to set default search for a text "/Stock" in the Many2One field Location (`location_id`) of model `stock.quant`.

This is the desired result after clicking a menu that calls the customized action window.

[image: search-by-name]

Right now, I can only type the word in the search bar to get the result in the image. However, I want to make it happen automatically upon loading this page.

I tried `<field name="context">{'search_default_location_id': '/Stock'}</field>` in my customized action window, but it gives me this error.

> invalid input syntax for type integer: "/Stock" LINE 1: ...ROM
> "stock_location" WHERE "stock_location".id IN ('/Stock')

Since I created all of these menu, action window, and view, I can customize anywhere among these components.

How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right solution for my case.

First, create a new customized search view that will be specifically called by the action window. Create a filter with the desired domain. For example, my case is "/Stock".

```
<filter name="stock" string="/Stock" domain="[('location_id.complete_name', '=ilike', '%/Stock%')]"/>
```

After that, use the search view in the action window and also set the filter to be default in that search view in the context.

```
<field name="context">{'search_view_ref':'the_search_view_id','search_default_stock': 1}</field>
```

As a result, the filter will be set as a default in the searchbar of the view upon visiting the view.